# Kendo Grid get selected row and assign to local variable

Tags: angularjs, typescript, kendo-grid

I am using a Kendo Grid with AngularJs and TypeScript. I am able to get the selected row but I cannot assign the result to a local variable as it seems to run in a different scope.

My grid has the following properties:

```
this.gridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
      data: this.items,
      pageSize: 10
    },
    selectable: 'row',
    filterable: {
      mode: 'row'
    },
    change: this.onItemSelect,
...
}
```

The typescript function is as follows:

```
onItemSelect(kendoEvent : any) {
  var grid = kendoEvent.sender;
  this.selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
}
```

selectedItem is defined in my Controller class:

```
export class ServicePackageModalController {
private selectedItem : any;
 ...
}
```

The problem is the this.selectedItem is undefined when I check it in another button event later on. I assume this is because the scope is different when the function gets called in the Kendo Grid, so 'this' means something else and not my controller class:

```
handleNext() {
 console.debug(this.selectedItem) //this is undefined here?
}
```

So my question is how do I assign this result to my controller class so I can access it later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I could see to solve this was adding the following code to my handleNext function:

```
  var entityGrid = $("#EntitesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
  var selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());
```

You also need to have an `id` attribute with the name `EntitiesGrid` on the kendo-grid directive.

Comment: this one just returns the latest selected row, how can I achieve the whole selected rows?